# Laravel: Parameterized query with IN() function only returns first in match

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm running a laravel database query:

```
 $relatedUsers = DB::select("Select Distinct user_id FROM customerLinks WHERE customer_id IN (?) ", array($currentUserCustomerLinks_csv) );
```

The variable `$currentUserCustomerLinks_csv` holds a csv string of the specific customer_ids I'm looking for.

When I run this query in laravel, the only `user_id`s returned for records that match the first value in the `$currentUserCustomerLinks_csv` string. all of the other values in the csv are ignored.

When I run the same query directly in my mysql database I get the full list of ids.

Is there something wrong with passing a csv string into the database facade when used in an `IN()` function? I don't see any examples of the proper way of performing a similar query in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The variable `$currentUserCustomerLinks_csv` holds a csv string of the specific `customer_id`s I'm looking for.*

Using `IN` will not give correct results on `csv` input.
There is `FIND_IN_SET` to use on such input values.
Any positive `int` returned is indication for a match found.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select FIND_IN_SET( 'in', 'Rav,in,der' ) found_indx_1
    ->      , FIND_IN_SET( 'no', 'Rav,in,der' ) found_indx_2;
+--------------+--------------+
| found_indx_1 | found_indx_2 |
+--------------+--------------+
|            2 |            0 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

**Change part of your code as below**:

```
$sql = "select distinct user_id from customerLinks 
         where FIND_IN_SET ( customer_id, ? ) > 0";  
$relatedUsers = DB::select( $sql, array( $currentUserCustomerLinks_csv ) );
```

**Refer to**:

- [***FIND_IN_SET( str, strlist )***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

  - Return the index position of the first argument within the second
    argument

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help and the doc reference. I wasn't aware of the FIND_IN_SET function.